# TextInput component wont get cleared

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have `TextInput` component which ain't get cleared when calling `clear()` on it's ref. The weird part is that I have other `TextInput` in another component and it works perfectly there. any idea what can it be?

NONE WORKING CODE:

```
         <View style={styles.addLinkContainer}>
          <TextInput
            autoCorrect={false}
            ref={input => { this.txtInput = input }}
            style={styles.linkInput}/> 
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.foo(this.fee)}}>
              <IconFA name="arrow-right" size={scale(30)} color="#a6a6a6"/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>


    foo = (url) => {
    ...
        this.txtInput.clear()
        this.txtInput.blur()
    ...

   }
```

WORKING CODE IN ANOTHER COMPONENT:

```
        <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" enabled style={{width:'100%'}}>    
           <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
            <TextInput
              multiline={true}
              ref={input => this.input = input}
              style={[newStyle]}
              onChangeText={(text) => this.commentPlaceHolder = text}
              value={this.commentPlaceHolder}
            /> 
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.foo()}>
              <IconFA name="rocket" size={scale(30)} color="#a6a6a6"/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </CardAction> 
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>


    foo = () => {
    ...
        this.input.clear()
    ...

   }
```

Comment: You are implicitly returning the working one: `ref={input => this.input = input}` but you're not returning the non-working one `ref={input => { this.txtInput = input }}`, try changing it to `ref={input => this.txtInput = input }`.

Comment: nice catch! unfortunately it didn't fixed the problem :(

Comment: any error on terminal or debgger console?

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN no everything works but the `clear()` , no errors

Comment: it is broken in react native current version, you can try some plugin https://github.com/nikolaiwarner/react-native-text-input-reset/

Comment: @Cherniv to be clear, it is good for ios too? I notice they talk about an android bug

Comment: not sure,  sorry